# Best a-little-advanced examples of dynamic programming

Tags: algorithms, education, dynamic-programming

I was offered by a professor to give some tutoring in his course of Algorithm Design, based on Kleinberg and Tardos' book. He suggested me to prepare two exercise on dynamic programming, one exercise for polynomial reduction, and another one for approximation algorithms.The exercise should be not too advanced, but not just routine (they should fill two hour of tutoring).

Then my question is: what are fascinating problems one can propose in dynamic programming?

Comment: The exercises in the K-T textbook are generally pretty good. Pick some from that book that the professor is not already using for homework.

Comment: You can find too many good DP problems on [Top Coder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static) site. If you see the algorithm matches, there are 250 and 500 point problems which are not so hard and not so easy. (depends to your definition of hardness, you can check both types).

Comment: CLRS also have many exercises (but no solutions, which is a plus for you).

Comment: This is a tad too broad for a single question; I'm removing two topics.

Comment: It still seems too broad to me.  We want focused, technical questions that admit a single objectively correct answer.  This seems to call for a "big list of X": a big list of dynamic programming exercises.  Such a list could be enormous.  I don't see how you'd pick a single objectively correct answer.  As such, it seems too broad for this site's format: fascinating question, but not a good fit for Stack Exchange sites, I'm afraid.

Comment: @D.W. In retrospect, I agree with you. Since the question has been upvoted, I can't delete it directly.